# Prevent people from modifying other people's rows with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to share a public URL to a Google Sheet with many people (potentially 1000 people or more), with edition permission.

I would like that anyone with the share link can **add their own rows and modify them** but:

- not modify someone else's row
- not delete someone else's row

How to do this with Google Sheets?

Comment: How many people? Does this people are able to follow instructions i.e. select a row and protect it, (for details about protection see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en) or do you need this to be automatic? Can you ask users to enter their email in the spreadsheet or in a dialog?

Comment: @Rubén Potentially 1000 people or more. So there is always the risk someone comes are deletes everything :) Yes one column might be "Email address".

Answer (score 2):

For few users, you could use the Google Sheets protection feature. Each editor should protect their row so only the spreadsheet owner and the editor could edit the row.

I'm not sure that this feature, and Google Sheets in general, will be able to handle so many editors for a use case like this as you might expect, so be cautious and be prepare yourself to handle limits and problems, i.e. there is a maximum of 100 tabs that can open a Google document (documents, presentations, spreadsheets) at the same time, some user interface elements to make it easier to manage large number of elements).

One option might be to use a Google Form setting it to allow that form submissions be edited. Each form response submission will have a unique edit URL but anyone with that URL will be able to edit the form response.

Another option might be to create a Google Apps Script web app.

Resources

- [Share files from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?hl=en)
- [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks @Rubén can a google form be easily linked in realtime to a google sheets? Each new form submission adds a row? or do I have to use a third party tool for this such as zapier?

Comment: @Basj 1) Yes, 2) Yes, each form submission adds a row, there is no need to use a third party tool.